# Make WooCommerce pages accessible for logged in users only

Tags: users, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a website using WordPress, and an e-commerce using WooCommerce. I would like my shop (and all its pages) to be seen by logged in users only.

Via the *User Access Manager* plugin, I have denied access to the shop page, but with a direct link to a product etc. one can access that particular page nonetheless, even if the user is not logged in.

How can I redirect users, who are not logged in, to another page if they try to access a WooCommerce page?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    if (
        ! is_user_logged_in()
        && (is_woocommerce() || is_cart() || is_checkout())
    ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

**What does it do?**
We check if a *not-logged-in user* wants to see a WooCommerce page, and redirect him/her to our home page.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The file functions.php is in my theme folder?? And how can i recall this function from the product page? Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code works fine for me. Many many thanks :)

Comment: Make sure you don't set any of the woocommerce pages as your homepage, because then site won't work anymore.

Answer (score 10):

I just changed the redirection to

```
wp_redirect( site_url('my-account/') )
```

so users are redirected on the "My-Account" page if not logged in or registered.

Comment: This is not the best method to redirect to the `My Account` page. It is better to retrieve the permalink of the My Account page that you linked in your WooCommerce settings. This way whenever the permalink is changed or you have a multi-language site running the permalink will still be correctly retrieved. In short: It's better not to hardcode permalinks/slugs (or URL's in general). A better method would be: `wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_myaccount_page_id' ) ) );`

Comment: you code missing  ;  it end

Answer (score 2):

I would change to this

```
wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) );
```

instead of

```
wp_redirect( site_url('my-account/') );
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why will this help, so other people could learn something from your answer?